# Meaning of execlp call arguments

Tags: c, exec

What is the meaning of the `execlp` arguments?

For example in `execlp("ls","ls","-l",NULL)` why are the first two arguments the same?

Where does this `execlp` look for the executable?

Comment: Did you read the man page for it? http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/execlp.3.html

Comment: The first two arguments don't have to be the same, but it is conventional to make them the same.  You could have `execlp("ls", "/usr/bin/passwd", "-l", (char *)0);` which runs the `ls` command but the value of `argv[0]` would be `/usr/bin/passwd`.  More realistically, older shells looked at the first character of `argv[0]` and ran as a login shell (processing `/etc/profile` and `~/.profile`, or whatever) if it was a dash `-` — so `execlp("sh", "-sh", "-i", (char *)0);` would run an interactive login shell for many shells.